# Autoplay policy in Chromium Version 124.0.6339.0 (Developer Build) (64-bit)

Tags: video, chromium, vimeo

I am using embedded videos in the some of the webpages and all was working fine until recently when these videos have stopped playing, throwing different errors. One example is vimeo.com itself where there is embedded video on the webpage and this page works fine in chrome but it does not play anything in chromium ( Version 124.0.6339.0 (Developer Build) (64-bit)).

In past some people suggested to use --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required flag in order to get it to work. I tried that but its still not playing these videos. Also i have found out that in case of vimeo videos are not playing even if i try to access the video URL link directly. An example video is https://player.vimeo.com/video/436960717 which plays fine in chrome but is not playing in chromium. When i hit the play button, i get the following error.

**Player error: The payer is having trouble. We'll have it back up and running as soon as possible"**

Any suggestions in this regard ?